# Can I run a try-except block (or similar) inside a Snakemake rule?

Tags: python, shell, snakemake

I trying to run a snakemake workflow. What I want to do is that if a given rule (`rule a`) works out send an email with a small text saying so, and if it fails then send another different email indicating an ERROR. I was wondering, is there a way in snakemake to run something similar to a try-except python block?

I have already tried out the try-except block with some commands inside a `shell()` directive, but it seems that I am not allowed to run any python code (`except` part of the block) once I have already written a `shell()` directive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your options are to convert your `shell` directive into a `run` directive with `shell()` functions or to use bash.  For bash, something like

```
shell:
    'MyCommandThatMayFail '
        '&& mail -s "passed" you@email.com '
        '|| (mail -s "failed" you@email.com ; exit 1)'
```

Should work for the email.  The `exit 1` is necessary to signal to snakemake that the command failed.

A final consideration, if you are using a job scheduler on a cluster, the worker nodes may not have network access so emailing will fail from the submitted jobs.

Comment: Thanks! This worked out for me. I didn't implement the exact same answer as I am using an if-else condition in there, but I took the main idea and it worked. The `exit 1` part is specially relevant here.

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this functionality is to add [`onerror` and `onsuccess`](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#onstart-onsuccess-and-onerror-handlers) to your workflows:

```py
onsuccess:
    print("Workflow finished, no error")

onerror:
    print("An error occurred")
    shell('mail -s "an error occurred" youremail@provider.com < {log}')
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I already knew that. Unfortunately this is not what I would like. Using this approach I only send one email in the end of execution, but I would like to send an specific personalized error email for each one of the rules that I have if they fail.